# Hide overflow of just one div

Tags: html, css

The question is how to hide the scrollbar of the select div, without hiding the global scrollbar on the right?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB1pa.png)

Comment: Only apply the style to that div? What exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to desired div style.

Answer (score 1):

If it over flows on the x-axis use `overflow-x: hidden` and on the y-axis, `overflow-y: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<element/selector>{
height: inherit;
width: inherit
}
```

or

```
<element/selector>{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

or

```
 <parent element/selector> <Child element/selector>{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).